# Is it a good practice to delete your own comments under different questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I think that everyone, at least once, has been in a situation where you post an inappropriate comment under some question or answer. For example, you misunderstood the author's point or just were inattentive or in a hurry.

In such situations you might want to delete such comment. Is that a good idea? Because sometimes people refer to you, and deleting the comment creates some gaps in conversation - this happens because the delete action should be mutual, but it's not always the case.

Am I right?

Comment: It's a fine art, to navigate the line between leaving things to support a conversation or appearing a total jerk. I try to keep a 3 to 1 okish person to jerk ratio.

Comment: In borderline cases I have been known to delete such a comment and post a new one that I was the one at fault. (It's rare.) (Not that I am at fault, but that I feel the need to post as much, I mean.) In cases where it does not really matter to the 'conversation', just delete it.

Comment: If the rest of the conversation isn't useful either you can always flag those comments for deletion as well.

Comment: I find that, if there has been an exchange of comments which then prove irrelevant or off-topic, if I delete mine fairly soon, it can encourage other participants to delete their responses as well, so there is less chance of leaving a broken trail.

Comment: In an ideal case, there shouldn't be any comments as both Q and A are so perfect that there is no need to comment. Aim towards ideal and delete all no-longer-relevant content. If need be edit them into the posts.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Like most of the times, the answer is: It depends.

If your comment is not essential, and it doesn't add anything useful to the post, then delete it. But please don't confuse *not essential* with *wrong*. And I mean that sometimes your comment might be a wrong attempt to provide a solution. In some cases, future users might find that "mistake" very helpful, especially when other users have corrected you elsewhere in the comments.

On the other hand, if your comment provides missing, or additional useful information, then it's obvious that it should be kept.

In conclusion, use your judgement. One answer can't cover all cases when you should or shouldn't delete a comment.

Comment: I like the way you think, Maroun.

Comment: "... then it's obvious that it should be kept", unless it's been incorporated into the answer, in which case it should be deleted.

Comment: @Oleksandr I'm glad my answer is helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Dukeling Not necessarily. Sometimes my eyes go directly to the highly upvoted comment, which usually has what I'm looking for. It doesn't harm to keep both of them.

Comment: Also if the comment is truly "inappropriate" as OP suggests, then it also should be deleted.

Comment: @Maroun one thing I miss in your answer: "even if the comment is wrong, don't delete it if someone referenced in a following comment correcting it and providing a comment that does provide an answer. deleting your comment might lead to the correct(ing) one becoming incomplete or, through the reference to the no longer existing comment: (a bit) harder to understand."

Answer (score 12):

I think in a lot of cases by deleting particular comments you’re doing other users a real service — to the point that it seems to makes some sense to periodically go back through your old comments in context (by re-reading them in the actual comment streams at the questions/answers where you posted them) and assess whether they’re still useful or whether they’re now just a distraction.

For one thing — in contrast to the case where you’ve deleted a comment another user’s comment refers to — consider the case where instead another user has since deleted a comment that one of your comments refers to. Now *your* comment is the one left there creating a gap in conversation.

And given that (as noted in the question here) comment-delete actions aren’t automatically mutual in any way — and also give that you don’t even  get any kind of notification when another user has deleted a comment from a comment stream where you commented — then unless you go back and periodically review your old comments, you have no way of knowing you’ve left behind a comment that’s since lost its context and now just become a distraction.

---

*(The rest of this is an incidental meta-reflection on why it can sometimes makes sense to edit or update a question/answer to add information, rather than posting a comment to begin with.)*

Given that comment streams have an ephemeral/unstable characteristic where, due to comment deletion, “conversation gaps” can end up happening that can’t really be fixed, and so comments can end up losing context and instead being distracting — then I think that suggests: in the cases where you have something to add of substantial informational value, then instead of posting it as a comment, it’s worth considering to edit the question/answer it’s related to and instead add it there.

The reason for trying to make sure all the useful information migrates into the question or answer is that unlike comments, which as noted in this Q&A here and meta discussions, can lose context and are immutable, something you add to a question or answers can be re-edited and updated later — importantly, even *collaboratively*, by users other than you. So that helps ensure your contribution can retain relevance in context rather than ending up just being a distraction.

Comment: I agree that editing the answer directly to place important and updated information can be very useful, especially in old upvoted answers. But sometimes the author does not want that, even if the person that asked the question is providing that information for him. Also, if the author has enough privileges, even his comments can be deleted (I have seen such a case). In this case, perhaps creating a Wiki answer with part of that answer and the new information may be justifiable...