# Why would a closed question lose all of its comments & edits?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've asked a question 20 minutes ago: *[What's the difference between empty and undefined in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272809/whats-the-difference-between-empty-undefined-in-javascript-array?noredirect=1#comment83529485_48272809)*

Within minutes, I got lots of comments answering my question, which I think were really helpful.

The question was marked as a duplicate of another question, *[Difference between new Array(7) and Array.apply(null, Array(7))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014973/difference-between-new-array7-and-array-applynull-array7)*, which I think it is a duplicate, because the answer also answers the question I'm having.

I did an edit to explain why it's not a duplicate of another question and some further comments.

However, the problem is:

1. The comments in my question are all gone
2. My edit seems to be over-written with a newer edit

I think the comments under a closed question shouldn't be removed because they're still related to the question itself. So I want to ask..

Why is Stack OverFlow designed to delete comments on a closed question?

Comment: Only comments that link to the duplicates are deleted, because they're now present in the banner at the top. The rest were simply deleted by their owners for whatever reason.

Comment: Hmm OK thx... I'll take this as a reason. it's really strange cuz only 1 commits raise a potential duplication and it's not linked to the questions marked duplicated with..

Comment: @Kaiido Your link was actually used. The duplicates list was edited after being closed to remove the one you linked. See the revision history of the post.

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry I didn't realize there were three suggestions. But the system just deletes comments by pattern match. Essentially something like "duplicate" followed by a link. I forget the exact criteria, but the it attempts to get rid of all duplicate suggestions when the question is closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Where did the comments go?

As indicated in comments to this post, the auto generated comment for the duplicate flag is removed when the post is marked as duplicate and the same information is moved to the banner.

In addition, comments as often removed by their authors, or moderators if a flag is raised, when the comments are no longer relevant.  A couple of meta posts (of many) on this topic are [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313718/7311767) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361942/7311767).

#### What happened to my edit?

As can be seen in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48272809/revisions), your edit was rolled back.  I am assuming it was rolled back because it was perceived that your additions did not add anything to the post.

Comment: Side note: not only the  edit did not add any new information, but it also added thank you notes: "BTW, people in StackOverFlow are really quick :D I can get answer within 1min. Thanks guys" which definitely should not be in the question/answer. Suggested reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK would read :D

Comment: Indeed, I didn't found the edit adding any relevance to the post, and even at the contrary for more than half of it. And the note about the first dupe-target was already obsolete when I rolled-back the post (Barmar did remove it from the dupe-list, as it probably got there without him noticing: it was a wrong target).

Comment: Also, chronic over-editor on that post. The post is closed as a duplicate, the edit is rolled back to revision 1, so the overzealous editor decides this is a good candidate for 3 separate, extremely minor edits? Wow, good thing "Google Chrome" was capitalized, I wouldn't have understood what the closed dupe was about otherwise.